# HTTP response after error handling

Tags: http

So, I saw here a couple of questions related to mine but I want to describe a more specific situation. Imagine your API always checks for the amount of daily requests made to an entry point. Once a specific client achieves this limit I'm returning 422 - "Unprocessable entity".

I guess I just want to consult whether someone has a different approach.

Comment: I'd consider HTTP 429 - Too Many Requests.

Comment: Nice call!. Feel free to post an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever there are too many requests being fired to your server, you can always respond with **HTTP 429: Too Many Requests**. [Check the RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6585#page-3).

> The 429 status code indicates that the user has sent too many requests
> in a given amount of time ("rate limiting").
>
> The response representations SHOULD include details explaining the
> condition, and MAY include a Retry-After header indicating how long to
> wait before making a new request.
>
> For example:

```
HTTP/1.1 429 Too Many Requests
Content-Type: text/html
Retry-After: 3600

..body..
```